# NodeJS - Create a Promise function that use Sequelize function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I am new to Promise and I have difficulty creating a Promise that will include a Sequelize function which already uses Promise.

I would like to something like this:

```
var geojson = require(path.join(__dirname, 'lib', 'geojson');

router.get('/[0-9]{3}/points.geojson', function(req, res, next){
    var codecs = req.url.split('/')[1];
    geojson.pointsToGeoJSON(codecs).then(function(geoJSON){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.end(JSON.stringify(geoJSON));
    });
});
```

**./lib/geojson.js:**

```
var path = require('path');
var Promise = require('promise');
var Geojson = require('geojson');
var Point = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'models', 'point'));

module.exports = {
    pointsToGeoJSON: function(codecs) {

        //this is a Sequelize function
        Point.findAll({where: {codecs : codecs}, raw: true})
        .then(function(points){
            var data = [];
            for(var i=0; i < points.length; i++){
                points[i].coordinates = JSON.parse(points[i].coordinates);
                data.push(points[i]);
            }

            //this is another asyn function
            Geojson.parse(data, {'crs': {'type': 'name', 'properties': {'name': 'EPSG:3857'}}, 'Point': 'coordinates'}, function(geoJSON){

                //this is what I want the function to return
                return geoJSON;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

How can I make the above `pointsToGeoJSON` function to use Promise, in order to be able to use `.then()`

Comment: Use bluebird to promisify everything. ```npm install bluebird --save```. I used it in every project. https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird

Comment: is'nt the same thing than npm promise?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, it can create single promises like in your case, but it also has a function called ```promisifyAll``` that can promisify a whole library. It's just a suggestion. That is why I didnt post it as an answer.

Comment: `Geojson.parse` doesn't return a promise, right? So you [cannot `return` from its asynchronous callback](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572), you should [promisify the function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) instead.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin promisifyAll seems not working with my module, nothing seems to be returned and the resquest is pending indefinately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have Promises so just do this:
    var path = require('path');
    var Promise = require('promise');
    var Geojson = require('geojson');
    var Point = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'models', 'point'));

```
module.exports = {
    pointsToGeoJSON: function(codecs) {

        //this is a Sequelize function
        return Point.findAll({where: {codecs : codecs}, raw: true}).then(function(points){
            var data = [];
            for(var i=0; i < points.length; i++){
                points[i].coordinates = JSON.parse(points[i].coordinates);
                data.push(points[i]);
            }

            //this is another asyn function
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                Geojson.parse(
                    data, 
                    {'crs': {'type': 'name', 'properties': {'name': 'EPSG:3857'}}, 'Point': 'coordinates'}, 
                    function(geoJSON){
                        resolve(geoJSON);

                    });
            });
        });
    }
};
```

See the link @bergi provided for an explanation of using Promises with callbacks and some alternatives.

Comment: I cannot make it works, when doing `geojson.pointsToGeoJSON(codecs).then(function(geoJSON){.. ` I got error undefined have no .then function

Comment: You also needed to return the promise from pointsToGeoJSON, Just edited my response to include the full solution.

Comment: ok but I have this error now: `Unhandled rejection (<{"type":"FeatureCollection","features"...>, no stack trac
e)` ??

Comment: Sorry! I had the reject/resolve arguments reversed. resolve should be first.

Comment: My! Thank you for your help with this